# Excel sumifs and rank / sort output

Tags: excel

I am trying to do the following:

Essentially, I want to use a sumifs function on a bunch of criteria which then calculates to see whether its $ value is > 10% of a total value. I want to return the top 10 values.

```
1. Name      2. Category    $ Value % of total
A                  1           4       2.5%
B                  2           5       7.5%
C                  3           7       10.0%
D                  4           2       10.0%
E                  5           8       5.0%
C                  6           3       5.0%
G                  7           5       10.0%
K                  8           9       10.0%
I                  9           1       10.0%
J                 10           2       10.0%
K                 11           7       10.0%
```

Is this obtainable?  The data set I will eventually use may have 100k+ rows. So I want a quick way to group all the names together, sum up their $values and %, and if they exceed 10% rank them based on the top 10.

Comment: It is unclear how you are making your calculations or what exactly you are after. What have you tried? Also, what happens if you have 200 entries all with the same value? How will you select the top 10?

Comment: The numbers that I am currently using are just arbitrary. If all 200 = the same. I am not too sure as yet how to pick which 10 to include. Perhaps I will select the 10 with the highest total $ value for their name type.

I have not tried too much as yet, due to the fact that I don't really know if this is even possible. I am looking for anyone that can put me in the right direction.

The only way I can think of at the moment, is to just write a formula which groups each name type together and then filter them in descending order. and simply take the top 10 that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table. Group by name, i.e. drag name to the row panel, sum the values, i.e. drag value to the values panel and set to sum. Drag values to the values panel again and set to show as a percentage of the grand total. Sort by that percentage, filter to show top ten.

That's what pivot tables were invented for. Just a few clicks to aggregate, sort, rank.

Not a single Sumifs in sight. Don't pre-load a question with an unsuitable function.